# MongoDB aggregate conditional - hide object based on conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From the database:

```
_id: "123123123123123"
question: "Question1"
answer: "some answer"
by: "user1"
__v: 0
```

There is a conditional I am trying to implement here. It does not work. If `by` is empty, then do not display `_id: "$question",`

```
        let answers = await Answer.aggregate([
            { $match: { $or: [{ by: user.email }, { by: user2[0].email }] } },
            {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$by", ""],
                    },
                    then: 0,
                    else: 1,
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$question",
                    data: {
                        $push: "$$ROOT",
                    },
                },
            }
        ]);
```

Outcome (wrong):

```
    {
        "_id": "Question1",
        "data": [
            {
                "answer": "some answer",
                "by": "user1"
            },
            {
                "answer": "some answer",
                "by": "user2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "Question2",
        "data": [
            {
                "answer": "some answer",
                "by": "user1",
            }
        ]
    },
```

**Expected outcome:**
I want to display only Question1 because `user2` does not have an answer (there is no user2 `by`). So display Question only if there are 2 `by`.

```
        {
            "_id": "Question1",
            "data": [
                {
                    "answer": "some answer",
                    "by": "user1"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "some answer",
                    "by": "user2"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Could you include some sample input data as well?

Comment: So you don't want a document with empty `by: ""` why not just implement it in `$match`? I don't see `by: ""` in your example so I don't quite understand what you try to do. Try do make input document correspond to your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `$or`condition and use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) in

```
 { $match: { $or: [{ by: user.email }, { by: user2[0].email }] } },
```

changed to

```
 { $match: { $all: [{ by: user.email }, { by: user2.email }] } },
```

Comment: I tried $all and $and too but they give me an error

Comment: unknown top level operator: $all

Comment: $and gives me an empty array

Comment: Please share your data model for the expected outcome. Thanks.

Comment: The expected outcome is in my post, at the bottom. Bascially, if `_id` has two answers (2 different users) then display it. If `_id` does not have two answers (zero or only 1) then do not display it. So `data` must have 2 objects for the `_id` to be displayed.